# python selenium local html source

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I want to get a local html source through selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver2')
driver.get("test.html")
html = driver.page_source
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

However, this error occurs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
 driver.get("test.html")
File "/Users/seula/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-
```

packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/Users/seula/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
 packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute

```
self.error_handler.check_response(response)

  File "/Users/seula/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-
```

packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument

(Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.130)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the `driver` it's a file and not url

```
driver.get(r'file:\C:\folder\test.html')
```